# Jenkins Docker container keeps shutting down randomly, any ideas why?

Tags: linux, jenkins, devops

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AqHJ.png)Jenkins container keeps shutting down without warning

Hello! I'm using Jenkins as Docker container, here is my command : docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 5000:5000 -d -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:lts. When i start this command everything is fine and i can work in Jenkins GUI for some short time and then this container just shut down without warnings and logs inside these container, it happens all the time. other containers continue to work normally and are not disabled.

Comment: Hi, please format your code; here is [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also, the use of images creates various problems. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

figured out - just add --restart=on-failure to docker run command

Comment: that is not the solution

Answer (score 0):

you can add `--restart=always` to the command, that should help, also I don't know if it is a typo or not but you bind the port `50000` not `5000`